# Java How to serialize any data into ORC format

Tags: java, hadoop, serialization, hive, orc

I am able to successfully convert any CSV file into ORC with the help of vectorized row batch. But as per the new requirement, I have to serialize any type of input data into ORC format. The data type of the input data is dynamic. It can be of any type. I have to serialize the input data(which is of any type, say CSV, Avro, etc,..) to byte array which can then be written into ORC file later. I have been unsuccessful to find anything that helps this requirement. Please show some light on how I should approach and what and all I can try to achieve this. Is there any in-built support for this in org.apache.orc

Comment: If you convert your input to a byte array, without any concept of colums or data types, then there is no Java object to "serialize"... It's just an arbitrary binary dump that will probably prove totally useless.

Comment: In other words the problem is not about _serialization_ into ORC ; it's about "automagic" de-serialization from your random inputs. Good luck with that.

Comment: Sorry, I think my question is not clear. Let me try to explain. Basically my application needs to serialize the input data that can be in any formats like CSV, Avro, etc,.. into ORC writer understandable format(This serialization part is what I meant by converting input data to byte array) and write it to a kafka topic. Later my application or some other application needs to read these data from kafka topic and write them as ORC files. FYI, the input data is enclosed in an object as an attribute, the same object has ORC schema as another attribute.

Comment: Sorry but that's weird -- with Kafka you normally use a message format (Avro, Protobuf, Thrift, or plain bloated JSON). Whereas ORC is a read-optimised format for analytics, where rows/messages are broken down into individual fields then field values are compacted separately. Using an intermediate binary message encoding specific to ORC feels weird. Or maybe weirdly innovative. Time will tell  : )